# String is not assignable to keyof Readonly<T> typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript2.0

I have problem on assigning string into react component state using typescript

```
export default class MainSection extends React.Component<{}, MainSectionState> {
    state = {
        filter: 'showAll'
    };
}

interface MainSectionState {
    filter: keyof TodoFilter;
}

type TodoFilterCallback = (todo: Todo) => boolean;
type TodoFilter = { 
    showAll: TodoFilterCallback,
    showActive: TodoFilterCallback,
    showCompleted: TodoFilterCallback,
};
```

In this case it should be okay to initial assign filter with 'showAll', but throw compile error below

```
error TS2415: Class 'MainSection' incorrectly extends base class 'Component<MainSectionProps, MainSectionState>'.
  Types of property 'state' are incompatible.
    Type '{ filter: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<MainSectionState>'.
      Types of property 'filter' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"showAll" | "showActive" | "showCompleted"'.
```

What should i do with this problem?. i'm using typescript 2.3.2, react 15.5.4, redux 3.6, and react-redux 5.0.5

Thank you

Comment: Likely related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `{filter: 'showAll'}` expression is `{filter: string}`, which is wider that `state`'s type. That's because `string` is a wider type (supertype) of `'showAll' | 'showActive' | 'showCompleted'` (the type of `filter` property in the state). It seems that you'll need to use a type cast:

```
state = <MainSectionState>{filter: 'showAll'};
```